# Excel VBA to print the date and page number in the header and footer

Tags: excel, vba, printing, pagination

I would like that whenever my page prints on the top left corner for the date to be printed and the bottom left for the page number.

How can this be done using the head command in excel.

Head = "value of the date"

and

Foot = "Page number"

I know there are other ways to do this however I was asked to do this using specifically these functions.

Comment: I may have made a mistake editing out the vb script you had written.  Exactly how are you accessing/implementing this print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  .LeftHeader = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy")
  .LeftFooter = "&P"
End With
```

Comment: see i'm not supposed to use leftheader

Comment: I have to use head and foot this is my main problem

Comment: @Tom, I know of no function called head and foot, so unless your company has a custom function, I think this is what they meant.  There is no 'Head' or 'Foot' in the Excel help.

Comment: here is the full back story, our company said the page was printed too slowly and contacted toshiba. Toshiba said to use head instead of .leftheader, I worked all day but head just does not work and I have to use it.

Comment: @tom, ok, I'll do some more research, in the meantime you might want to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230382/how-to-print-faster-in-excel-vba

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers wow, all these years and no one caught that, should be the "&", edited now.

Comment: @LanceRoberts 15K views too, I'm glad your still around to fix it so it's correct moving forward!

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  .LeftHeader = Format(Now(), "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")                                     ' Saturday, July 13, 2019
  .LeftFooter = "Page &P of &N"
End With
```

Date Formats --> https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-format-date/#Format-Date-Using-VBA-Display-Several-Items-Of-The-Date

Update:

I used to use `.LeftFooter = "Page " & ActiveSheet.Index & " of " & ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count ' Page 1 of 2` but this gave inconsistent results and I found it better to use `.LeftFooter = "Page &P of &N"`

See here for more `&Foo` examples --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers